# Substituir valores de colunas especificas em uma matriz (R)

Tags: r, matriz

Na matriz (**ret_matriz**)

```r
      IBOV        PETR4        VALE5        ITUB4        BBDC4        PETR3    
[1,] -0.040630825 -0.027795652 -0.052643733 -0.053488685 -0.048455772 -0.061668282
[2,] -0.030463489 -0.031010237  0           -0.040229625 -0.030552275 -0.010409016
[3,]  0           -0.027012078 -0.022668170  0           -0.080732363  0.005218051
[4,] -0.057468428 -0.074922051 -0.068414670 -0.044130126 -0.069032911 -0.057468428
[5,]  0.011897277 -0.004705891  0.035489885  0           -0.006024115  0
[6,]  0.020190656  0            0.009715552  0.014771317  0.023881732  0.011714308
[7,] -0.007047191  0.004529286  0.004135085  0.017442303 -0.005917177 -0.007047191
[8,] -0.022650593 -0.029481336 -0.019445057  0           -0.011940440 -0.046076458
[9,]  0.033137223  0.035274722  0            0.060452104  0.017857617  0.046076458
```

Gostaria de substituir os valores 0 por 0.0000000001, somente das colunas 3 ate 5, tentei o codigo abaixo

```r
ret_matriz[ret_matriz==0,3:5] <- 0.00001
```

Porem recebi o seguinte erro

Error in ret_matriz[ret_matriz==0,3:5] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long

Aonde estou errando ? Qual a forma correta de atingir o resultado descrito acima ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na matriz, quando você coloca a condição `ret_matriz==0` você já está fazendo um subset da matriz inteira, linhas e colunas.

Então o que você tem que fazer nesse caso é primeiro é filtrar somente as colunas que você quer, por exemplo:

`ret_matriz[,3:5][ret_matriz[,3:5]==0] <- 0.00001`